# Context changes on the call of $.each() function

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I am using Jquery $.each to get all the elements which belong to a particular class and I wanted to call a  function on each of those one after another.To achieve this, I called following function:

```
 var elements = $('.colorpickerHolder');
                    elements.each(self.ApplyColorPicker());
```

I can see on the runtime that elements has three elements which is correct. Now, when I call self.ApplyColorPicker, I am refereing to each current element with $(this). Surprisingly, $(this) is not current element.

My code is working under knockout framework and both pieces of code are under a viewModel. and inside ApplyColorPicker $(this) becomes my viewModel. I am not sure why is that. Any reasonings?

Below is my ApplyColorPicker code just of the review:

```
 self.ApplyColorPicker = function () {
           $(this).ColorPicker({
                color: '#0000ff',
                onShow: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                    return false;
                },
                onHide: function (colpkr) {
                    $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                    return false;
                },
                onChange: function (hsb, hex, rgb) {
                    $(this).css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
                }
            });
        };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in a reference to the function itself to `each`, not what the function evaluates to. In other words use `self.ApplyColorPicker` instead of `self.ApplyColorPicker()`.

```
 var elements = $('.colorpickerHolder');
 elements.each(self.ApplyColorPicker);
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are calling `ApplyColorPickers` in the `.each` statement, meaning it is only being called once and is passing the result of that function into `.each`, rather than a reference to the function. This should work instead:

```
elements.each(self.ApplyColorPicker); //Without the () after ApplyColorPicker
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do:

```
elements.each(self.ApplyColorPicker);
```

The problem is that `self.ApplyColorPicker()` actually calls the function. What you need to pass to `$.each` is a reference to the function.